# Where can I download Microsoft Office?

Tags: licensing, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

Here at our company, we've lost our install CDs for Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007. We have, however, still our volume license key.

**Where can I download MS Office Pro Plus 2007?**

Microsoft's download website doesn't seem to offer the 2007 version, and the various file hosters only offer demo versions.

Comment: If you're signed up to one of the full on volume licence programs then try http://licensing.microsoft.com or otherwise contact your reseller

Comment: What Rob said is correct. There should be pre-pid'd images (with the generic VL key in them if it's that sort of a license) on your licensing site.

Comment: Just cheked. https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Downloads/DownloadsAndKeys.aspx - still has 2007 available for download.

Comment: "closed as too localized", but 1000+ times viewed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sign in to http://licensing.microsoft.com/
- Click on **Downloads & Keys**